# Save form when date is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to save the form when the date is selected from datepicker without a submit button.

However, I do not know what shall I type into *update.js.erb* to assist me to do that.

Here are my codes:

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@place , :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
div class="field">
<%= f.label :select_start %><br />
<%= f.text_field :select_start, id: "place_select_start" %>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
                  var startDate="<%= @place.start_date %>";
                  var endDate="<%= @place.end_date %>";


                  $("#place_select_start").datepicker({

                    value: new Date(),
                    minDate: new Date(startDate),
                    maxDate: new Date(endDate),
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    beforeShowDay: unavailable


                  })
                });
```

Comment: Does the javascript in `update.js.erb` gets included when rendering the `show` action? I think `update.js.erb` is rendered when you call the url `PUT place/1/update.json`.

Comment: i have not code update.js.erb as I am not sure what needs to be coded inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will trigger the form submit when the date is changed:

```
$('#place_select_start').datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: hi, it works. thanks for your help! :) however, the pages refreshes. is there any way to not make it refresh and update?

Comment: You should use `ajaxSubmit()` instead of `submit()` then. For this you need the ['jQuery Form Plugin'](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Also have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1960245/2637573).

Comment: Or you could use Turbolinks with RoR4. This will 'hide' the refresh.

Comment: the ajaxSubmit() does not work. after i use it, the datepicker does not come out.

Comment: i remove turbolinks as it caused some of my javascript files to not load properly.